# How can I include the current workspace name in the default argument value of a rule?

Tags: bazel

Let's say I have a rule:

```
blah = rule(
    attrs = {
        "foo": attr.string(default = "@HELP@"),
    },
)
```

I want the default value of `foo` to contain the name of the workspace that invokes the rule. How can I accomplish this?

(Note: An acceptable approach is to leave a placeholder in the value and replace it when the rule uses the attribute, but I can't figure out how to get the current workspace there either. The closest I can find is `ctx.label.workspace_root`, but that is empty for the "main" workspace, and e.g. `external/foo` for other things.)

`ctx.workspace_name` does not give the correct answers. For example, if I `print("'%s' -> '%s'", (ctx.label.workspace_root, ctx.workspace_name))`, I get results like:

```
'externals/foo' -> 'main'
'externals/bar' -> 'main'
```

...which is wrong; those should be 'foo' and 'bar', not 'main' ('main' being my main/root workspace). Note that labels from those contexts are e.g. '@foo//:foo', so Bazel does apparently know the correct workspace name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as getting the workspace name, this seems sub-optimal, but also seems to work:

```
def _workspace(ctx):
    """Compute name of current workspace."""

    # Check for meaningful workspace_root
    workspace = ctx.label.workspace_root.split("/")[-1]
    if len(workspace):
        return workspace

    # If workspace_root is empty, assume we are the root workspace
    return ctx.workspace_name
```

Per Kristina's answer and comment in the original question, this can then be used to replace a placeholder in the parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a placeholder attribute and then use [`ctx.workspace_name`](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/skylark/lib/ctx.html#workspace_name) in the implementation.

```
def _impl(ctx):
  print("ws: %s" % ctx.workspace_name)

blah = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
)
```

Comment: No, that gives the wrong answer in other than the main workspace. (See updated question.)

Comment: Oh, good point. It actually should give the correct result in the future (once https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1262 is in), but until then you're stuck with the hacky script (sorry).